# Issue with Awesome Font Icons

Tags: css, icons, font-awesome

I'm stucking on a little issue with awesome fonts icons. I've a wordpress website and I use awesome icons, in particular "battery" icons.

In 1st page I can see the battery icon, but in 2nd page I can't see battery icon, just white space, anyway in 2nd page I can see all icon types, except battery icon...

I can notice that in battery icon I don't see the code ::before in  tags...
maybe this could be the issue... ?!

```
<i class="fa fa-battery-full"></i>
```

where I see the icon the code is:

```
<i class="fa fa-plug">::before</i>
```

Comment: have you tried the complete code FA is giving ? `<i class="fa fa-battery-full" aria-hidden="true"></i>`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: see table in center of page the differencences on the battery icons.. visible or not visible 1. http://www.exeprogetti.it/prodotti/software-gestionale-edison-garden 2. http://www.exeprogetti.it/prodotti/software-webmobile

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the last version of FA? try to change the version

[Download Here](http://fontawesome.io/)

Maybe the FA that your used is old, Try that.

Comment: see table in center of page the differencences on the battery icons.. visible or not visible 1. http://www.exeprogetti.it/prodotti/software-gestionale-edison-garden 2. http://www.exeprogetti.it/prodotti/software-webmobile